# Worst Case Analysis

Tags: computational-complexity

For the following algorithm, the function base() is to be considered the basic operation. The size of the input is given by n. Perform a worst-case analysis:

> for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
>   
> for(j = 0; j <= n; j++)
>   
> for(k = i; k <= i*i; k++)
>   
> if(condition(i,j,k))
>   
> b[i][k] = base(b[i][j])
>   
> else
>   
> b[i][k] = b[j][k]

Could anyone guide me through solving this? I'm new to this topic and struggling to find a coherant example online.

Comment: Worst case analysis would mean the maximum iterations of this triple loop. Clearly $i$ will go $n$ times. What about $j$ and $k$

Comment: j will go n+1 times and k will go i^2 - i + 1 times I believe, might be wrong though. the if(condition) else () confuses me; what if the condition is never true? Our prof. doesn't teach us any material related to the things he assigns, and the TA's struggle horribly to answer questions. Thanks for the -1 though, whoever did that.

Comment: Welcome Math.SE! Take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $LaTeX$ syntax. Guidelines for [homework questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question), please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution. If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition here is immaterial. In any case, the triple loop will be executed as follows.

The outermost $i$ loop will be executed $n$ times
The next one  $j$ loop will be executed $(n+1)$ times

The inner $k$ loop is the interesting. The $i$th time it is executed $(i^2 - i + 1$) times. (Take the case when, say $i = 3$, it will be executed for $k = 3,4,5,6,7,8,9$.

So the total executions of the inner loop are $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (i^2 - i + 1) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (i^2 - 3i + 3)= \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6} - 3\frac{(n)(n+1)}{2} + 3n\tag{...for inner loop}$$

The final answer is in simplifying this and multiplying with the $n(n+1)$ iterations for the 2 outer loops.

Comment: does: $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (i^2 - 3i + 3)$ assume that you already did the n+1 (j loop)? I understand $i^2 - i + 1$ being multiplied by $\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}$, and then $\sum_{i=0}^{n}$

Comment: would it be safe to assume the worst-case runtime is $\theta{(n^4)}$?

Comment: The last term is order $n^3$   so finally it will be order $n^5$

Comment: Am I correct when saying the worst case and the best case are of order $n^5$, thus being able to describe the algorithm as being big theta of $n^5$? Thanks for all the help also, much appreciated.

Comment: @Xian. Yes. Absolutely.

Comment: From looking at it, it looks like $n^4$ order, however is it $n^5$ because we have $(n^2 + n)(2n + 1)$ in the first term (order $n^3$), then we need to multiply by n and n + 1, which would raise its order another two times, going to $n^5$?

Comment: @xian. Yes. That's how it is done

Comment: turns out your answer was incorrect, it it $n^4$, as I thought in the previous comment. -1.

Comment: @Xian. I will certainly take a look at it